# totally ordered semigroups

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, algebra, ordering

Given a semigroup is it possible to give a total order to it?

If not possible in the general case then what about the case of finitely generated finite semigroups?

Does there exist a natural extension of the syntactic order given to a semigroup w.r.t. an upper set? (currently it only induces a partial order)

Comment: Do you want the total ordering to be compatible with the semigroup operation in some way? If yes, then the integers modulo $n$ are a finitely-generated finite (semi)group that seem difficult to order.

Comment: Yeah I would like the order to be stable. And yes, you are right, giving a total order to the above semigroup would effectively make all the elements equal. In fact for finite semigroups with only one generator, we will always get a "lasso"-like structure and that would mean that giving a total order would make the loop elements all equal, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is always the case for semigroups, but for groups, yes. This also occurs in many finitely-generated (but not necessarily finite) abelian groups.

Comment: I am not sure to understand the third part of your question. Are you considering an upper set $U$ of some ordered semigroup $S$? Please give more details.

Comment: @david-richerby The computer science part is the reference to the syntactic order, which is unfortunately not very clear. Is is possible to migrate this question?

Comment: Semigroup theory, particularly finite semigroups are a part of theoretical computer science. The latter are intimately related to finite automata.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin You say there's CS content, so I'll retract my close vote instead.

Answer (score 2):

**Monogenic semigroups**.
Consider the case of a [monogenic semigroup](monogenic semigroup), that is, a semigroup $S$ generated by a single element $s$. If $S$ is finite, then it can be totally ordered if and only if it is [aperiodic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperiodic_semigroup), that is, if there exists a positive integer n such that $s^n = s^{n + 1}$. In this case, the order could be $s \leqslant s^2 \leqslant \dotsm \leqslant s^n$.
If $S$ is not aperiodic, then it contains a finite subgroup, and the only compatible order on a finite group is the equality, as you observed.

If $S$ is infinite, it can also be ordered by $s \leqslant s^2 \leqslant s^3 \leqslant\dotsm $.

**Arbitrary semigroups**. An interesting example is the free monoid $A^*$ equipped with some [shortlex order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortlex_order). Shortlex orders are total and are compatible with the concatenation product.

**Second question**. I am not sure what you mean by a "finitely generated finite semigroup" since every finite semigroup is finitely generated. Thus I suppose that the question is whether the order of a finite ordered semigroup can be a total order. There are some examples which are not monogenic, for instance the ordered semigroup $(S, \leqslant)$ with $S = \{a,b\}$, $a \leqslant b$,  $aa = ba = a$ and $ab = bb = b$.

**Third question**. See my comment.

Comment: Sorry for not replying.... I was off the grid. 
About my third question, I meant just a subset (sorry for the confusion) which later (after associating a syntactic order) becomes an upper set (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: To be completely honest, I am actually interested in the case of finitely generated involutionary semigroups where the generators are hermitian elements. And I want a total order because I want to have an order between an element and it's involution. This order should be stable as well. Also if u and v are two sequences of elements in the semigroup which multiply up to the same element then they must be equal (w.r.t order)

Comment: The closest thing I could find to this was the syntactic order given to semigroups but I couldn't extend the same to my case. I would be happy to know of any alternative.

Thanks!